# PHP array and string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array containing dates (year) and position.
I need to build a string out of it, where:
Every position is separated by a / if it's in a different year ; and a - must appear if there was no result on a year. And if we have a -, then there is no need to use the / to separate the years ...
I'm struggling to build a logic and code for it.

Example:

```
array(7) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2015" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "2" } 
  [1]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2015" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "4" } 
  [2]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2015" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "5" } 
  [3]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2015" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "5" } 
  [4]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2015" 
    ["hformpos"]=> int(0) } 
  [5]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2014" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "2" } 
  [6]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2014" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

Should show: 32/05542

And

```
array(7) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2014" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "2" } 
  [1]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2014" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "4" } 
  [2]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2014" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "5" } 
  [3]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2014" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "5" } 
  [4]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2013" 
    ["hformpos"]=> int(0) } 
  [5]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2011" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "2" } 
  [6]=> array(2) { 
    ["year"]=> string(4) "2011" 
    ["hformpos"]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

32-5542-

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried something ? (BTW: You may want to explain a little bit more what you want; I don't get it)

Comment: You can try a for-loop - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, I've tried lots of options ... But it will make it even more confusing if I list all the routes I went to!

Comment: @user1606597 Then please just add like your best attempt so that we can show you where you made the mistake; Also can you please explain a bit more what you want, because I don't really see the pattern behind this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the array is sorted in the descending order of the dates(year).

```
$year_flag = $arrays[0]["year"];
$result = "";
foreach( $arrays as $array )
{
    if($year_flag == $array["year"]){
        if( $array["hformpos"] !==0){
            $result.= $array["hformpos"];   
        }else {
            $result.= "-";  
        }

    }elseif( $array["hformpos"] ===0){
        $result.= "-";  
    }else{
        $result.= "/";  
        if( $array["hformpos"] !==0){
            $result.= $array["hformpos"];   
        }else {
            $result.= "-";  
        }
    }
    $year_flag = $array["year"];
}
```